# How to use an encrypted HEX file in LTSpice?

Tags: ltspice, model, hex

I have downloaded a [model](https://www.onsemi.com/support/design-resources/models?rpn=NVHL020N120SC1) of a MOSFET from ON Semiconductor  and have a problem with it. The "model" looks like this:

```
* LTspice Encrypted File
* 
* This encrypted file has been supplied by a 3rd
* party vendor that does not wish to publicize
* the technology used to implement this library.
* 
* Permission is granted to use this file for
* simulations but not to reverse engineer its
* contents.
* 
********************************************************************************
* On Semiconductor SiCMOSFET 1200V Model Library
* Last Update: Jan. 28, 2020
* Model Version: 1.5
* Simulator: LTspice
*
********************************************************************************
* Model Contacts:
*    James Victory     James.Victory@onsemi.com
*    Ken He            kencanzhong.he@onsemi.com
*    Scott Pearson     Scott.Pearson@onsemi.com
*    Hyeongwoo Jang    Hyeongwoo.Jang@onsemi.com
*    Stan Benczkowski  Stan.Benczkowski@onsemi.com
*    Yunpeng Xiao      YunPeng.Xiao@onsemi.com
*
********************************************************************************
* Reversion History:
*   Vers.   Date        Brief Description
*   1.0     02/12/2019  Generated models for NTHL080N120SC1, NVHL080N120SC1, and SVHL080N120SC1
*   1.1     08/26/2019  Added models for NVBG020N120SC1.
*   1.2     10/09/2019  Update the base model for largeDie devices to the vers1i.
*   1.3     12/12/2019  1. Added VG dependence to the body diode forward IV in the largeDie device
*                          base model.
*                       2. Added product models for NTBG020N120SC1, NTHL020N120SC1, NVHL020N120SC1
*                          NVH4L080N120SC1 and NTH4L080N120SC1.
*   1.4     01/10/2020  Added product models for NTHL040N120SC1, NVHL040N120SC1, NTHL160N120SC1, NVHL160N120SC1
*                       NTH4L160N120SC1 and NVH4L160N120SC1.
*   1.5     01/28/2020  Added product models for NTH4L020N120SC1, NVH4L020N120SC1, NTH4L040N120SC1, NVH4L040N120SC1
*
********************************************************************************
* Usage:
* This library contains 3 and 5 pin(or terminal) models. The models include 
* self heating effects and were characterized under pulse conditions from 
* 10us to 1ms conditions. 
*
* The 5p models contain 2 additional pins tj (or junction temperature) and
* tcase (or device case thermal terminal). 
* tj should always be left floating or can be connected to a very
* large resistor (>1meg). This terminal is meant to provide the user with
* output information on the junction temperature under operation. For model
* verification purposes against the data sheet and isothermal device simulations
* for example, tcase should be connected to a voltage source with value {TEMP},
* the simulator ambient temperature. For system/module level simulations that
* include thermal effects, tcase should be connected to the device-module
* thermal interface node such as the heat sink interface point.
*
********************************************************************************
* Support devices:
*   NTHL080N120SC1_3p, NTHL080N120SC1_5p
*   NVHL080N120SC1_3p, NVHL080N120SC1_5p
*   SVHL080N120SC1_3p, SVHL080N120SC1_5p
*   NVBG020N120SC1_4p, NVBG020N120SC1_6p
*   NTBG020N120SC1_4p, NTBG020N120SC1_6p
*   NTHL020N120SC1_3p, NTHL020N120SC1_5p
*   NVHL020N120SC1_3p, NVHL020N120SC1_5p
*   NVH4L080N120SC1_4p, NVH4L080N120SC1_6p
*   NTH4L080N120SC1_4p, NTH4L080N120SC1_6p
*   NTHL040N120SC1_3p, NTHL040N120SC1_5p
*   NVHL040N120SC1_3p, NVHL040N120SC1_5p
*   NTHL160N120SC1_3p, NTHL160N120SC1_5p
*   NVHL160N120SC1_3p, NVHL160N120SC1_5p
*   NTH4L160N120SC1_4p, NTH4L160N120SC1_6p
*   NVH4L160N120SC1_4p, NVH4L160N120SC1_6p
*   NTH4L020N120SC1_4p, NTH4L020N120SC1_6p
*   NVH4L020N120SC1_4p, NVH4L020N120SC1_6p
*   NTH4L040N120SC1_4p, NTH4L040N120SC1_6p
*   NVH4L040N120SC1_4p, NVH4L040N120SC1_6p
*
********************************************************************************
*
** Begin:
 72 90 B0 68 54 0D 9A 07 A9 04 16 53 E8 32 9E 34
 1A 71 F7 82 AF 56 34 5A EF 25 6A BD 21 44 17 A4
...
 0D 50 65 6D 98 1C 07 C6 21 7F D1 6A F4 E8 F6 F5
 29 F0 DF 44 9F D7 2A 8A
* End 3708261714 511592688
```

So there is no .SUBCKT commands or something else... I haven't found any tutorials in Internet either. How can I import this model in LTSpice?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Use it just like any other 3rd party subcircuit, except don't expect it to be shown in the flattened netlist as more than a single, cryptic line (i.e. if things go bad, you're out of luck).

Comment: Read here https://www.mouser.com/pdfDocs/AND9783-D.pdf (page 24)

Comment: Thank You for the tutorial, I will try to follow it and write a feedback later!

Comment: @G36 Thank you, very much! That was exactly that I had looked for!

Answer (score -1):

usually these models are made only for specific, paid-for, SPICE simulators and are not available to the wider public. It might say with which program it may be compatible, but otherwise try finding a similar model that is unencrypted that you can use with freeware.

Comment: The very first line says it’s for LTSpice.

Comment: Thank You for the answer. If you will go through the [link](https://www.onsemi.com/support/design-resources/models?rpn=NVHL020N120SC1), You will find that there are three models: for pspice, ltspice and simetrix. I have downloaded for LTSpice, so it might be right...

Comment: Well even better if it's for LtSpice. Hope it works. I know I can't use these types of encrypted models on TINA.

Comment: G36 says:
Read here mouser.com/pdfDocs/AND9783-D.pdf (page 24) – G36 Aug 19 at 17:29